# Email body as the attachment in a Sharepoint list

Tags: list, attachments

I'm trying to create a flow that will:

1. receive an email from a shared mailbox
2. create a list item on SharePoint
3. and add the **email message** as an attachment to that list item

Preferably, when opening the aforementioned attachment, I'd like it to open in Outlook like you would see with any other email.

I've searched in a variety of places on this topic, but they mostly address adding an attachment that's attached to the email itself.

I've tried exporting the email as a step, but cannot figure out how to make it an attachment. How does "Message ID" help?

And whenever I "Apply to Each", the only option available is "Attachments", but seems to only be associated with an attachment to the email. I removed the additional fields in this step as they don't seem helpful at this point.

[image: screenshot]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You currently have a snapshot of the "Apply to each" method with the Email Attachments action -- this would loop through the attachments that came on the triggering email -- is this your intent?  Do you want to save the email's attachments as List Item Attachments?  Or do you want to grab the contents of the Email Message to save as the List Item Attachment?

Comment: Thanks for replying, willman. The "apply to each" was a result of me piecing together what I've found from searching the web so far, and not something I want to loop. Instead, your latter comment is correct in that I want the email message to be what's saved as the attachment to the list item being created each time the flow is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Automate does have a built-in SharePoint action named `Add attachment`.  More detailed explanation included below this sample screenshot:

[image: screenshot of Flow with expanded add attachment action]

If you configure the Site and List parameters of this action identically to the values you use in your `Create item` action, then you can use the `ID` returned from `Create item` to populate the `ID` parameter of `Add attachment` (i.e. `@{body('Create_item')?['ID']}`).

You can give the new attachment any name you like, though you could potentially name it after the triggering email's subject if you strip out potentially unsafe characters.  While you generally have very little control over what application opens a given file on the end-user's computer, if you give your attachment a filename with the `'.msg'` extension, it will open with the end-user's default configured desktop email application (so hopefully, Outlook).

And finally the "File Content" of the `Add attachment` action can reference the message body of the triggering email (i.e. `@{triggerBody()?['body']}`).

new image added:
[image: new image]

[image: second new image]

[image: error message when trying to open email attachment]

[image: updated screenshot]

Comment: This is good stuff, willman. I am still having a bit of trouble though after following your instructions.

The attachment is still not saving. Is there a way for me to attach new screenshots?

Comment: And another thing I noticed, the flow still shows as "running" when I view the "Runs" section of the flow's detail page. The item is being created though, just not with an attachment.

Comment: There's no way to add images to a "comment", but you can always edit your question and additional images/screenshots to the question post.

Comment: Make sure you completely removed that "apply to each" action.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the images. "apply to each" was already removed.   ???

Comment: I have to wait for my edits to be approved, but until then I also noticed that the details of the run history indicate that there is a "bad gateway" in the add attachment step. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Is your Flow connecting to an on-prem SharePoint site?  "bad gateway" should't be possible using a built-in action to connect to SharePoint Online.  Have you double checked that attachments are enabled in this list (i.e. if you add an item manually through the browser, can you manually upload an attachment to that item)?

Comment: It looks like maybe you have chosen the wrong Dynamic value for your File Content parameter.  Make sure, when you choose the value that you find the section in the Dynamic content that is labelled with the same name as your trigger (`"When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox"`).  If you do not see "Body" under that section, you may need to click "see more" next to the title of the section to get that option.  You should also be able to just cut and past `@{triggerBody()?['body']}` into the File Content input field rather than messing with the Dynamic content selector.

Comment: Getting closer! Originally, I left blank "Has Attachments" and "Include Attachments" because it seemed to me it was for the incoming email -- not to pave the way for me to create an attachment later in the process. I chose yes for the latter field and an attachment was made (with .msg ext). But I get an error when opening that attachment. I'll post a screenshot in my orig post, but briefly it says I don't have permission to view it. I'm the admin of the site and have access to the shared mailbox, so I'm confused.

Comment: Another oddity, I save the flow so I'm thinking it's ready to go. I send a test email, but an item isn't created until I re-open the flow and save it again. It's like I have to kickstart it. It should be automatic, so is there a delay I should expect?

Comment: Chances are the opening and re-saving had nothing to do with it.  Flows can take anywhere from 5-15 minutes sometimes to be auto-triggered.  The delay seems to get longer the more frequently you trigger, so testing sometimes can be frustrating.

Comment: Btw, the reason you have to keep waiting for your edits to be approved is because you are editing the answer that I posted.  If you Edit your original question to add more info or images, you always have permission to Edit your own post without approval.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may have to purposefully download the list item attachment before opening in Outlook.  clicking on a file link usually saves it in a protected internet temporary files that Outlook probably doesn't have access to (to prohibit malware from being able to access your email client)

Comment: Sorry about editing your answer. I had no idea I was doing that. Also, thanks so much for sticking with me on this subject. I'm almost there as I've been able to create the attachment as a txt file, but when it opens it comes out as html. I tried several kinds of steps (one at a time) to convert it (using [Body]), but it always comes out html. Suggestions please?